# Multiple keyboard shortcuts for switching workspaces

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

I'd like to have an alternative keyboard shortcut for switching between workspaces. Is there a way to have multiple shortcuts for the same action? I guess that if I knew the system command that triggers the switch I could create a custom shortcut, but I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to search around and found that using xdotools you can switch between workspaces with

`xdotool set_desktop --relative -- -1` and `xdotool set_desktop --relative 1`

So I added those commands as custom keyboard shortcuts and they work like a charm